# Salesforce Checking if Values Changed (Trigger Handler)

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to check if Account field changed from a specific value.

If old Account's flag was "Open" and new Account flag is not open

Then perform some check.

```
private void doCheck(map<Id, Account> oldAccounts, map<Id, Account> newAccounts){
   List<Account>newList= new List<Account>();
    List<Account>oldList= new List<Account>();

    oldList= oldAccounts.values();
    newList= newAccounts.values();

 //check if old account flag changed from "open" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void doCheck(map<Id, Account> oldAccounts, map<Id, Account> newAccounts){

    for(Id i : oldAccounts.keyset()){
       Account old = oldAccounts.get(i).Flag__c;
       if(old.Flag__c == 'Open' && old.Flag__c != newAccounts.get(i).Flag__c){
          // do your magic here
       }
    }
}
```

If you're going to run some queries for that - you shouldn't make queries in a loop. Some helper `Set<Id>` where you'd put the Ids and later run the queries for all Account Id's in that set might be best idea... hard to say what exactly do you need.

the `keyset()` and `get(someKey)` methods from `Map` collection are described in Apex help: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_methods